# nginx failed to start on centos 7 minimal

Tags: nginx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAUpw.png)[sudo] password for ahmed:
● nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-03-14 07:57:48 EDT; 11min ago
Process: 19198 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 19195 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 1493 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 14 07:57:48 localhost.localdomain systemd[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdxXl.png): Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Mar 14 07:57:48 localhost.localdomain nginx[19198]: nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "server_name" direct...nf:41
Mar 14 07:57:48 localhost.localdomain nginx[19198]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Mar 14 07:57:48 localhost.localdomain systemd[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdxXl.png): nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 14 07:57:48 localhost.localdomain systemd[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdxXl.png): Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
Mar 14 07:57:48 localhost.localdomain systemd[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdxXl.png): Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Mar 14 07:57:48 localhost.localdomain systemd[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdxXl.png): nginx.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
[ahmed@localhost nginx]$[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdxXl.png)

[[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEETE.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTATb.png)

Comment: Can you add the contents of the config file to the question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your config(/etc/nginx/nginx.conf) has some errors in it. You can get more information about the errors by running the `nginx -t` command.

Comment: after running the command 
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "server_name" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:41
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: So the line number 41 has the error. Can you post the config file content in the question?

Comment: im trying to configure nginx tas reverse proxy mode

Comment: Please add the config file content to the question. So that we can help.

Comment: attached now kindly check

Comment: It looks like you have an incomplete config there. See the nginx docs on how to set it up: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/